# In jQuery, how to http get a gzip file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, curl, gzip

I run a simple http server myself, using node.js and express.js.

```
var express = require('express');
express().use(express.static(__dirname)).listen(3000);
```

In my static content folder, there are two files for testing purposes: `myfile.csv` and `myfile.csv.gz`. Their sizes are 685 and 403 bytes, respectively. I used `curl -I` to view their response header. The `Content-Length` field correctly reflects the file size.

```
curl -I http://localhost:3000/myfile.csv

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "685-1377648449000"
Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2013 11:12:40 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Aug 2013 00:07:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 685
Connection: keep-alive

curl -I http://localhost:3000/myfile.csv.gz

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "403-1377677249000"
Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2013 11:12:48 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Aug 2013 08:07:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 403
Connection: keep-alive
```

Then I write the below JavaScript code snippet in order to fetch the two files in client browser. It correctly alerts 685, which is the size of `myfile.csv`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "myfile.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.length);
    },
});
```

However, when I change the url field to `myfile.csv.gz`, the script alerts 387 instead of 403. I cannot get the full content of `myfile.csv.gz`. What's wrong?

I tried changing `dataType` from "text" to "application", but encountered a "parse error" saying "No conversion from text to application."

I also tried adding `headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip" }`, but encountered an error saying "Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"".

How can I get the full content of a gzip file using jQuery in client browser?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the solution myself. Add `mimeType: "application/octet-stream; charset=x-user-defined"` and it is good to go.